# Preprocessor checking defined

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I can check predefined value like:

```
#ifdef SOME_VAR
  // Do something
#elif
  // Do something 2
#endif
```

If I have to check 2 values instead of 1. Are there any operator:

```
#ifdef SOME_VAR and SOME_VAR2
  // ...
#endif
```

Or I have to write:

```
#ifdef SOME_VAR
   #ifdef SOME_VAR2
      // At least! Do something
   #endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard short-circuiting *and* operator (`&&`) along with the `defined` keyword is what is used in this circumstance.

```
#if defined(SOME_VAR) && defined(SOME_VAR2)
    /* ... */
#endif
```

Likewise, the normal *not* operator (`!`) is used for negation:

```
#if defined(SOME_VAR) && !defined(SOME_OTHER_VAR)
    /* ... */
#endif
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that `&&` doesn't work with `#ifdef`, you have to use `#if` and `defined()` :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `defined` operator:

```
#if defined (SOME_VAR) && defined(SOME_VAR2)

#endif
```

`#ifdef` and `#ifndef` are just shortcuts for the `defined` operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
#if defined(SOME_VAR) && defined(SOME_VAR2)
// ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`#if defined(A) && defined(B)`

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to get away from using #ifdef and just use #if, since "empty symbols" evaluate to false in the #if test.

So instead you could just do

```
#if SOME_VAR && SOME_OTHER_VAR
    // -- things
#endif
```

But the big side effect to that is that you not only need to #define your variables, you need to define them to be something.  E.g.

```
#define SOME_VAR         1
#define SOME_OTHER_VAR   1
```

Commenting out either of those #defines will make the above #if test fail (insofar as the enclosed stuff not being evaluated; the compiler will not crash or error out or anything).